# Office 365 Distribution List - how to NOT get the message I send to the group if I am a member?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365

I am a member of this specific Office 365 Distribution list.
When I send a message to this group this message goes to my own inbox also.

Microsoft 365 groups do not have this behavior.
Sender does not get their own email message to the group.

Is there a way around this?
Office 365 setting or do I have to setup an Outlook rule?

Answer (score 0):

It’s not feasible to achieve that because dg (distribution group) is used to distribute emails to every member in it.

What you can do is to click the Distribution Group in "To" Bar and delete yourself Alias.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).